# Optoelectronics community

Tags: discussion

Can I ask you please if you know of any community that discusses optoelectronics? I am currently working on the physics behind them and it would be really helpful to have a second opinion.

Comment: This is not a good question for this site; anyway, you can ask the more electronic-related questions here, and in physics.stackexchange the more theoric ones...But before that, read the FAQ please

Answer (score 5):

You can feel welcome to ask about optoelectronics here.  We have tags for

- [optoelectronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optoelectronics)
- [opto-isolator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opto-isolator)
- [led](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/led)

and many more.  Be aware that these are usually approached as *components*, not systems to be designed themselves, but we do have a number of people who do chip design and I'm sure would love to ask and answer questions about optoelectronics.

Questions about how optoelectronics works on the atomic level (unless your goal for asking is to make a decision in a design, and not solely to educate yourself) are good candidates for our [physics site](http://physics.stackexchange.com).  They don't appear to have very much dissussion on this topic, but you might check these tags:

- [Electromagnetic-energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/Electromagnetic-energy)
- [Electricity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/Electricity)
- [Light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light)

Finally, while it is my belief that Electrical Engineering and Physics can handle this topic, you're welcome to propose a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also [photodiode], [laser], [light], [electromagnetism], [optics], ... Also possibly connected: [sensor], [communications], ...

Comment: @ThePhoton - Yeah, I'd lumped those into 'and many more'. The 'related tags' sidebar on many each of these tags has even more possibilities.

Comment: @ThePhoton For future reference, you can get a tag to link by typing [tag:name ] with no extra space... so [tag:photodiode]

Answer (score -2):

You'll find a wide range of skills and interests on the [PICList](http://www.piclist.com). Despite the name "PIC microprocessors" are just part of what gets discussed. While I won't guarantee that you will find a world class expert there, there is every chance that you may. I and a number of 'Stack Exchange members are also PICList members - complementary. We have people from many of the major electronics companies and people with a very wide range of skillsets. You have to register to participate but it's spam free and you can leave any time you wish.

Comment: @Giwrgos: The PIClist may be useful, but be careful.  It is run over the top Politically Correct so you can't tell someone to RTFM even when that's the appropriate answer.  The PIClist has decended into drivel and volume is way down in recent years.  Russell neglected to mention he is one of the admins there.

Comment: On stack exchange if you go around RTFMing people the community will register complaint votes against you as well as downvoting you. Even approaching that without using the terminology can get you complaint votes when people vote with their feelings and don't actually read what is said. Whereas PICList has a substantially different format - there is no voting system to help evolve those who are consistently rude and abusive - just guidelines on expected behaviour. Quite why that needs a "be careful" warning I know not.

Comment: ... The list has an "Off topic" area where driveling is allowed within reason if people feel they must. In the core technical areas the focus is technical. Regardless of any of the above, there are world class experts in SOME subjects there and it's easy to ask and se if that applies to any specialist area.
// ... admin ... -> modesty prevents  ... yada yada.  (I said I was a member)

Comment: And the phantom downvote is because this is terrible advice and not at all appropriate? Yes?

Comment: I didn't do the downvote, but perhaps it's because you are advertising something vaguely competetive with Stack Exchange.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, This is meta. The same rules do not apply here. The reason someone downvotes you is because they disagree, it has nothing to do with the quality of your post. I disagree with this post because they are asking where to go and this site makes sense for it. There are a million competing sites that have the knowledge, but since it is on-topic here, why send them away? It is not an attack of any sort, my downvote is just my way of voting how I feel.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, on the note of you consistently sending people there, not mentioning you are an admin for the site and heavily involved is hiding some of your affiliation to me, but that is a personal feeling. If you are going to advertise for a site there are [promotion rules](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). I would suggest always disclosing your affiliation when you send people there.

Comment: WFT? I got here from the main site, and didn't notice this was in meta until Kortuk's comment.  I guess we're not in Kansas anymore.

Comment: @Giwrgos: The "be careful" warning is because the PIClist is run by a closed clique of admins.  Not only is their view way off to one side, but they actively discourage open discussion about the list on the list.  Dictatorships eventually devolve into protection of the dictators being the highest priority.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Yeah, we really need a different color scheme on the meta site. It seems like most non-top 5 SE sites have the same problem, though.

Comment: @SimpleCoder There is a different color scheme between the two sites, they just aren't a major difference.

Comment: @OlinLathrop This question was closed as off-topic on the main site and then migrated to meta. Keeping the link active on the main site helps for people to find questions that they were actively interested in when they saw it on the main site.